# Keeping track of javascript libraries in github

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, version-control, github

As development progresses I use more and more javascript/jQuery libraries that I find in github (I know there are other sources, but github is the most prominent).

The problem arises when I notice the library has update with bug fixes or new features or worse - backwards incompatible changes to other libraries.

Is there something like [Gemnasium](https://gemnasium.com) for javascript libraries? 
What is the best way to keep track of libraries I use which are not gemmed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using a package manager such as [Bower](https://github.com/bower/bower). It's the `gem` for javascript and other client side assets.

There are others, but I recommend Bower, because it integrates well with GitHub. Many popular components can be found in the [Bower package registry](http://sindresorhus.com/bower-components/), but if they aren't, Bower also supports pulling dependencies directly from a git url.

Bower allows you to specify dependency versions with [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) with support for version ranges, and when you run `bower update`, it updates your project's packages, if new versions are avaiable within the constraints you've specified.